# I put too much oil in my car, the level has been corrected now but it's still smoking

Tags: ford, oil, taurus

I put two quarts of oil in my car, then it just started throwing out smoke almost immediately out of exhaust pipe. Drove it home less than a mile, my husband said i put too much oil. So he drained the two quarts out. Now it's throwing out blue smoke, not as bad as it was. Is it okay to drive car and let it just burn the excess off. That's what my husband said.

Comment: How many wiles have you driven since the oil level was corrected?

Answer (score 4):

If the oil is at the correct level now driving the car should be fine. Take it easy on the engine until it stops smoking. The smoke is likely coming from the residue of the excessive oil from the overfill and will burn off over the next little while.

Answer (score 1):

This can cause problems because if the oil is too high, the crankshaft or other parts up higher in the engine can strike the oil, and make it foam. Foamy oil does not properly coat the moving parts in the engine, and will therefore cause quicker wear.

Also, if the smoke is coming from the tail-pipe due to the extra oil, that could be a significant problem. Oil should generally not be introduced in the combustion process in a 4-stroke engine, and definitely not in your car's engine, IIRC. The fact that it is could indicate a larger problem. I don't know offhand if simply over-filling the oil can cause the oil to get into bad places, or if that means a vital seal has broken. Someone else may know more there.